# Macro to choose "Save" NOT "save as" when prompted on Internet Explorer 11 message bar at the bottom

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

i wonder if you can help!
i wrote a code to navigate through a certain website of my company to retrieve an excel sheet from our server and set this macro to run in certain intervals and it worked fine.
problem is that in my code i used the `SendKeys` method to click on the save button when prompted by IE 11 to Open, Save or Cancel. 
i found out that my code is PAUSED when i lock my PC and anyways PCs are locked automatically if inactive for security purpose. when i come back and unlock my PC, i see the code starts at the point of SendKeys.
PLEASE DISREGARD THE IDEA OF TASK SCHEDULER AS WON'T WORK!!!
so is there any code to automatically save this xlsx file?
many thanks in advance :)

```
Sub mySub()

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    WebSite = "example.com"
    logSite = "https://example.com/logoff.do"
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate WebSite
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set unElement = .Document.getElementsByName("username")
        unElement.Item(0).Value = "my username"
        Set pwElement = .Document.getElementsByName("password")
        pwElement.Item(0).Value = "my password"
        .Document.forms(0).submit
        '.quit

        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop


        Set expElement = .Document.getElementsByClassName("nav__action dropdown-trigger js--tooltip")
        expElement(0).Click

        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        .Document.getElementById("obb_EXPORT_EXCEL").Click

    End With


 application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
SendKeys "%S", True

   Const SOME_PATH As String = "C:\Users\Ali\Downloads\"


Dim file As String


file = Dir$(SOME_PATH & "BFUR *" & ".xlsx")

application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
If (Len(file) > 0) Then
  Workbooks.Open(SOME_PATH & file).Activate


End If
application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
ActiveSheet.Range("A4:BC600").Copy



Windows("macro testing final.xlsm").Activate

Range("A3").Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

     [L:L].Select
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With
Range("A3").Select
application.CutCopyMode = False

application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:40"))
Workbooks(file).Activate
application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False


With New FileSystemObject
    If .FileExists(SOME_PATH & file) Then
        .DeleteFile SOME_PATH & file
    End If
End With



   Windows("macro testing final.xlsm").Activate
   Worksheets("Pivots").Activate

    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

    application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    Worksheets("Email").Activate
    application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))



Dim EmailSubject As String
Dim SendTo As String
Dim EmailBody As String
Dim ccTo As String
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheets("Email").Range("A1:E72")

Range("A1") = "Hi All," & vbNewLine & "Please find the below report  generated at " & Format(Time, "hh:mm") & "." & vbNewLine


r.Copy

EmailSubject = "tNPS Update at " & Format(Time, "hh:mm")
SendTo = Range("Q10")
ccTo = Range("Q10")


Dim outlookApp As Outlook.application
Set outlookApp = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set outMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)



With outMail
.Subject = EmailSubject
.To = SendTo
.CC = ccTo
.body = EmailBody
.display

outMail.display
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor


'paste as Table (remove the comma)
wordDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False


.send
End With
Set outlookApp = Nothing
Set outMail = Nothing


   Windows("macro testing final.xlsm").Activate
   Sheets("Raw").Select
   Range("A3:BC900").Select
   Selection.ClearContents
   Range("A3").Select


    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate logSite
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

objIE.Quit

 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Without sharing your code, how would you expect anyone to have valid ideas on how to help you?

Comment: @DavidBarker sorry about that. code is above...i wish if you can help

Comment: all i wish but couldn't find on the web is something more reliable than SendKeys to save this file :)

Comment: is there an actual URL to the document in the getElementById("obb_EXPORT_EXCEL"). element?  If there is it would be better to parse it and get the url to the file and download the file directly.

Comment: @Sorceri there is. The problem is with the message bar that appears at the bottom of IE with the save prompt. SendKeys won't work if my workstation is locked

Comment: @AliS  if you have a URL you can use Microsoft.XMLHTTP to download it and avoid sendkeys.

Comment: @Sorceri thanks I will try it and feed you back

Comment: @DavidBarker your help is also much appreciated. considering the fact that i posted the code as you adviced

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to save it using just the URL.

Sub SaveInternetFile(myURL As String)

```
savePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'exit sub if the file already exists
If fso.FileExists(savePath & "FileName.xls") Then
    Set fso = Nothing
Exit Sub
End If

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
WinHttpReq.send

'myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile (savePath & "FileName.xls")
    oStream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: i have tried it but all it does is creating an empty file in the savePath i assigned with no attempt from the code to connect to the URL i defined

Comment: please check above and let me know please